# Adding events in Fullcalendar on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, cakephp, codeigniter, events, fullcalendar

I just implemented Adam Shaw's popular calendar called 'fullcalendar' (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) using CodeIgniter. But I require addition and other operations on events from my database. I was able to find one CakePHP plugin with the same purpose from here, http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/events-plugin.

Since I'm not in touch with CakePHP, Can anyone help with this on CodeIgniter..?

Comment: what do you want? Convert it from being a CakePHP-plugin to a CodeIgniterplugin?

Answer (score 1):

this might help a bit:
http://pyonk.co.cc/codings/53

but there is really no avoiding manually working with your own database
(i haven't seen any codeigniter fullcalendar plugins working end-to-end)